# What application was this chart made in?

Tags: data-visualisation, chart-design

I need to create scientific charts for data analysys. The ability to automatically generate maximum and minimum slope with the given uncertainty would be excellent.

Here is an examlpe of the result I want to achieve:
[image: example graph]

Comment: Can't you do that in Excel or Libre office?

Comment: I think you could create this in almost any program that allows you to draw lines.  This is _way_ too broad and impossible for us to even determine

Comment: my guess would be it is made in matlab. What tool _you_ should use, depends on what programmes you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any scientific/statistical analysis tool should make this a breeze. Some tools (in alphabetical order) that you should consider are:

- Gnuplot, ← free
- Mathematica,
- Matlab,
- Octave, ← free
- Python, SciPy and Matplotlib, ← free
- R and RStudio, ← free
- Etc.

On the other hand, while you could use Excel or Calc, I would advise against this. There are several reasons, but mainly they won’t scale with your needs and are error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for this list! I know Excel-type tools are not suited for the task, I'll try the ones you listed.

Comment: @TTkacki the reason excel types arent good for the task is that your computation is extre,ely hard to verify in them so it is next to impossible to review your work.